# Mute Button in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, mute

So here is my question. I have a expandable banner. When expands a video is starting to play. My task was to insert an on/off button for the sound in the video, and i did that. But the problem is that i can't reach my button because when i try to move the mouse to the button the expandable area disappear because I'm moving to the button areas. Here is the code too.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;    
import flash.media.SoundMixer;


cierre.gotoAndStop(1);
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0); 
video_player.autoPlay = true;
video_player.source = "video_500x374.f4v";

video_player.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finVideo);

stop();


b2_btn.buttonMode = true;
b2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, aBanner1);
b2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);





var clicktag=(stage.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag)?  stage.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag:"http://www.vasava.es";
function onClick(e:MouseEvent){
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(clicktag),"_blank");
}




function aBanner1(e:Event):void{
video_player.stop();
this.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function finVideo(e:Event):void{
video_player.stop();
cierre.play();
}

function setMute(vol) {
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform (0,1);
sTransform.volume = vol;
SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform; 
}
var Mute:Boolean = false;
mutebutton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleMuteBtn);

function toggleMuteBtn (event:Event) {
if(Mute) {
    Mute = false;
    setMute(0);

}else{
    Mute = true;
    setMute(1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put the mute button *in* the expanded portion of the banner itself, or just have the expanding banner mute the audio automatically with no need for a second button push. Which to use depends on your specific application and client requirements.

Comment: The button is in the expanded portion! But still doing the same :)

Comment: Oh, I think I see. When you move the mouse pointer over the button, an event is triggered that the pointer has left the expanded area, which collapses it? Is that correct? If so, you could simply have the mouseLeave event code detect that the pointer is over your button and not collapse in that case. Do you need sample code?